# Is there a way to simulate a website button-click in android studio or calling it's javascript code?

Tags: java, android, web, button, simulate

how can I simulate a button click, which is calling javascript-code in android studio?

It's like a follow button.

I have to login in this website. For now I do that with Jsoup.
Then to follow, I have to click a button (the button calls javascript code).

I would like to automate that in android studio with own methods.

Comment: android studio is an IDE, it can't click buttons, but the apps you make using it potentially could, meaning that any reference to android studio is mostly irrelevant here :)

Comment: I assumed it was clear that I was looking for something I was doing in code and not through the IDE

Comment: Try using [HtmlUnit](https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/javascript-howto.html).